# Redis SSL Errors In Logs - No Actual Issues?

Tags: ssl, redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

I have a strange question. I by all rights believe I have a fully functional 6 node (3 masters, 3 replicas) working with Redis 6.2.6 on Ubuntu Server. The client key appears to work and I get responses from all nodes as expected.

However, my logs for all 6 nodes are spamming:

> Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL
> routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number (conn: fd=20)

Even at the lowest logging level I believe they have, warning, this keeps happening. Am I missing something and I actually DO have a problem or is there a bug and a way to get this to stop spewing this beyond turning off logging?

```
Config:

port 0
bind 127.0.0.1
tls-port 6381
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
appendfsync everysec
tcp-backlog 65536
tcp-keepalive 0
maxclients 10000
loglevel warning
logfile "/var/log/redis/redis-cluster-6381.log"
 
tls-replication yes
tls-cluster yes
tls-auth-clients no
tls-protocols "TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3"
tls-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
tls-ca-cert-dir /opt/redis-ssl
tls-cert-file /opt/redis-ssl/redis-cluster-01.mydomain.pem
tls-key-file /opt/redis-ssl/redis-cluster-01.mydomain.key
tls-ca-cert-file /opt/redis-ssl/digicert-ca.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

Di you ever find the solution to this?

I have the same problem.  As you mention it appears that there is no impact, but it is annoying.  What is more frustrating is that I have (what I think is) an identical set (I am using Sentinel; same redis version 6.2.6) and the problem does not occur there.

What I also see is that the message comes up immediately after “Accepted 127.0.0.1:38348”  and if you look at the it points to that same ID as being used for the redis-cli so it looks like it could be something to do with communication from “this” machine and to re-stress I have no issues connecting from Redis Insight 2, Python and redis-cli works fine

We did have an issue connecting to the “OK” instance from .net (Stack exchange) but it looks like that was just a Stack Exchange parameter.